# containerCreating after a drain on K8S

Tags: kubernetes

After trying to make a drain on one node of my cluster I have this kind of error:

```
Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "gitlab-postgresql-stolon-keeper-2": Error response from daemon: all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused": unavailable
```

I'm using and K8S 15.4
docker v18.09.9

Comment: Your pod is trying to connect to some sort of dependency and is failing. Since you drained a node, it is likely that the required resources didn't spin up in time. If you kill this specific pod and let it spin up again, do you get the same error?

Comment: It's a log of docker and not dependant of pod